# Display Product Attibutes Label insted of Product Attibutes code in Exported CSV file

Tags: attributes, magento2, export-to-csv, admin

I want to show product attibutes label instaed of product attributes code in exported csv file from backend admin for first column.How can I achieve functionlity.

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what "backend admin" might refer to.

Comment: it means 'Magento Admin'.